# Querying a List of Objects

Tags: c#, linq, microsoft-metro

I currently have a list of "Day" objects.
The class definition for Day contains two strings:
-name
-hours

What I need to be able to do is find all Day(s) in the List that have the same hours and format them into one item.

Ex.

```
Sunday 8am - 9pm
Monday 8am - 10pm
Tuesday 8am - 10pm
Wednesday 8am -10pm
Thursday 9am - 10pm
Friday 9am - 11pm
Saturday 8am - 11pm
```

So, Monday Tuesday and Wednesday all have the same hours. I need to create a new list off the original that would look something like:

```
Sunday 8am - 9pm
Mon-Wed 8am -10 pm
...
...
```

Is there a simple way to do this with LINQ?

Comment: Only consecutive days should be grouped?

Comment: Only days with the same to and from hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GroupConsecutive` extension method, which you will find at the end of answer, you can do following:

```
List<Day> days = new List<Day>
{
    new Day { Name = "Sunday", Hours= "8am - 9pm" },
    new Day { Name = "Monday", Hours= "8am - 10pm" },
    new Day { Name = "Tuesday", Hours= "8am - 10pm" },
    new Day { Name = "Wednesday", Hours= "8am - 10pm" },
    new Day { Name = "Thursday", Hours= "9am - 10pm" },
    new Day { Name = "Friday", Hours= "8am - 11pm" },
    new Day { Name = "Saturday", Hours= "8am - 11pm" },
};

var query = from g in days.GroupConsequtive(d => d.Hours)
            select new {
                Name = g.Count() == 1 ? g.First().Name :
                       String.Format("{0}-{1}", g.First().Name.Substring(0, 3), g.Last().Name.Substring(0, 3)),
                Hours = g.Key
            };
```

Enumerating results:

```
foreach (var item in query)            
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Name, item.Hours);
```

Output:

```
Sunday 8am - 9pm
Mon-Wed 8am - 10pm
Thursday 9am - 10pm
Fri-Sat 8am - 11pm
```

Extension method for consecutive grouping:

```
public static class LazyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupConsecutive<TKey, TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> source, Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        if (!source.Any())
            yield break;

        var comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
        Grouping<TKey, TElement> group = null;

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var key = keySelector(item);

            if (group == null)
                group = new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(key);

            if (comparer.Compare(group.Key, key) != 0)
            {
                yield return group;
                group = new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(key);
            }

            group.Elements.Add(item);
        }

        yield return group;
    }

    private class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
    {
        public Grouping(TKey key)
        {
            Key = key;
            Elements = new List<TElement>();
        }

        public List<TElement> Elements { get; private set; }
        public TKey Key { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Elements.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

How it works? It creates grouping (custom class, which implements IGrouping interface) and adds consecutive elements with same key value to that group. If new key value arrives, then grouping is returned. Thus all sequence is grouped by consecutive key values.

Comment: @ZachJohnson welcome, it was interesting to implement generic consecutive grouping extension :)

Comment: @DipenduPaul thanks! Actually recently I created [better implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21484271/470005) which has better implementation of group concept and does not checks group for null on each iteration :)

Answer (score 1):

This is close to what you want:

```
        IList<Day> days = new List<Day>();
        days.Add(new Day { Name = "Sunday", Hours = "8am - 9pm" });
        days.Add(new Day { Name = "Monday", Hours = "8am - 10pm" });
        days.Add(new Day { Name = "Tuesday", Hours = "8am - 10pm" });
        days.Add(new Day { Name = "Wednesday", Hours = "8am - 10pm" });
        days.Add(new Day { Name = "Thursday", Hours = "9am - 10pm" });
        days.Add(new Day { Name = "Friday", Hours = "9am - 11pm" });
        days.Add(new Day { Name = "Saturday", Hours = "8am - 11pm" });
        var grouped = days.GroupBy(d => d.Hours).ToList();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var group in grouped)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", group.Key, group.Select(g => g.Name).Aggregate((list, nextday) => list + ", " + nextday));
        }
        var table = sb.ToString();
```

The output is:

8am - 9pm: Sunday

8am - 10pm: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

9am - 10pm: Thursday

9am - 11pm: Friday

8am - 11pm: Saturday

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> days = new List<Tuple<string,string>>
(
    new Tuple<string,string>[]
    {
        new Tuple<string,string>( "Sunday", "8am - 9pm" ),
        new Tuple<string,string>( "Monday", "8am - 10pm" ),
        new Tuple<string,string>( "Tuesday", "8am - 10pm" ),
        new Tuple<string,string>( "Wednesday", "8am - 10pm" ),
        new Tuple<string,string>( "Thursday ", "9am - 10pm" ),
        new Tuple<string,string>( "Friday", "9am - 11pm" ),
        new Tuple<string,string>( "Saturday ", "8am - 11pm" )
    }
);

ILookup<string,string> table = days.ToLookup( k => k.Item2, v => v.Item1 );

table[ "8am - 9pm" ]; // Sunday
table[ "8am - 10pm" ]; // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
```