# how to count continuous values in a list with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, indexing

I've a list like this:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 999).Select((n, index) =>
        {
            if (index <= 333 || index >=777)
                return 0;
            else if (index <= 666)
                return 1;
            else
                return 2;
        });
```

So, Can I find how much indexes have same value continuously? For example;

`query[0]=query[1]=query[2]=query[3]... = 0, query[334] = 1, query[777]=query[778]... = 0.`

First 334 indexes have 0, so first answer is 333. Also Last 223 indexes have 0, so second answer is 223..

How can I find these and their indexes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SonerGönül, I rolled back the edits, since they changed the meaning of the question...

Comment: Maybe you should keep the fixes to grammar and formatting?

Comment: @Magus I am too lazy to merge your edits into a correct one.

Comment: @L.B _Hmm_, I agree. Thanks.

Comment: What should happen when the same value is in mutiple segments, are they seperate results, do you sum or, do you ignore lower counts?

Comment: @Jodrell with Sergey's answer, I get this result and this is useful for me: http://i.hizliresim.com/epXOnJ.png

Comment: @SergeyBerezovsky's answer is better than my and other offerings because it returns an `IGrouping`, I can see that would be useful is many cases but not yours, since you'd use the default comparer for int. Do you really need to enumerate n values you know to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extension for consecutive grouping of items by some key:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, T>> GroupConsecutive<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext()) 
            yield break;            
        else 
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            var comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            TKey groupKey = keySelector(iterator.Current);

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                var key = keySelector(iterator.Current);
                if (!list.Any() || comparer.Compare(groupKey, key) == 0)
                {
                    list.Add(iterator.Current);
                    continue;
                }

                yield return new Group<TKey, T>(groupKey, list);
                list = new List<T> { iterator.Current };
                groupKey = key;
            }

            if (list.Any())
                yield return new Group<TKey, T>(groupKey, list);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can return `IEnumerable<IList<T>>` but that will be a little different from concept of group, which you want to have, because you also want to know which value was used to group sequence of items. Unfortunately there is no public implementation of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` interface, and we should create our own:

```
public class Group<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private TKey _key;
    private IEnumerable<TElement> _group;

    public Group(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> group)
    {
        _key = key;
        _group = group;
    }

    public TKey Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _group.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now usage is very simple:

```
var groups =  query.GroupConsecutive(i => i) // produces groups
                   .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() }); // projection
```

Result:

```
[
  { Key: 0, Count: 334 },
  { Key: 1, Count: 333 },
  { Key: 2, Count: 110 },
  { Key: 0, Count: 222 }
]
```

Comment: I get an error like this: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class. I can't solve this.

Comment: @team16sah do exactly as error says - define extension method in a **non-generic static** class. Your class is not static or it is generic (or both)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, there is no error. In addition, I've edited my question depending on your answer. Could you please help me if there is a solution for this?

Comment: @team16sah there is small issue in my method. Keeping default value as initial key value was really bad idea. Now all works. Also I will revert your question to previous edit, because Update is really different question (or it should be comment to answer proposed by me)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `GroupConsecutive` extension method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881363/smart-grouping-with-linq) you can just get the counts of each group:

```
query.GroupConsecutive((n1, n2) => n1 == n2)
     .Select(g => new {Number = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetContiguousCounts<T>(this IEnumerable<T> l, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp)
    {
        var last = default(T);
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var e in l)
        {
            if (count > 0 && !cmp.Equals(e, last))
            {
                yield return count;
                count = 0;
            }
            count++;
            last = e;
        }
        if (count > 0)
            yield return count;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> GetContiguousCounts<T>(this IEnumerable<T> l)
    {
        return GetContiguousCounts(l, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };
        var b = a.GetContiguousCounts();
        foreach (var x in b)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

For the simple test case, it outputs 1, 2, 3. For your case 334, 333, 110, 222 (the last value is not 223 as you asked in your question, because you only have 999 elements, not 1000).

Answer (score 0):

erm, how about this, most efficient implementation I can think of.

```
 IEnuemrable<KeyValuePair<T, int>> RepeatCounter<T>(
         IEnumerable<T> source,
         IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var e = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (!e.MoveNext())
    {
        yield break;
    }

    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    var last = e.Current;
    var count = 1;
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(last, e.Current))
        {
            count++;
            continue;
        }

        yield return new KeyValuePair<T, int>(last, count);
        last = e.Current;
        count = 1;
    }

    yield return new KeyValuePair<T, int>(last, count);
}
```

enumerates the sequence exactly once and only allocates variables when necessary.