# Sorting Groups to display them by date of containing element (LINQ)

Tags: linq, sorting, linq-group

I'm not sure if this is possible.
My class I have a list of looks like this:

```
class Person
{
 string Firstname
 string Lastname
 DateTime Timestamp
}
```

Now I would like to **create groups** by **Firstname** and **Lastname**.

- John Deer, 3:12
- John Deer, 6:34
- John Deer, 11:12
- Tom Kin, 1:12
- Tom Kin, 3:49
- Tom Kin, 4:22
- Markus Fert, 11:23

Further more I would like to **sort** this groups by their **Timestamp**, the last should be first while the **groups should stay to display them** in a listView.

- Markus Fert (Group Header)

  11:23       (Content Element)
- John Deer

  11:12

  6:34
- Tom Kin

  4:22

  3:49
- John Deer

  3:12
- Tom Kin 

  1:22

Hope any Linq genius can help me solving the problem :)
Thanks!!

---

Much Thanks to Sergey, worked like a charm!

Further I would like to create a **custom Class for my group Key** to display different additional things in my ListView headers. (not only a spliced together string)

I would like to assign my query to an IEnumerable like this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<Header, Person>> PersonGroups
```

Where the header contains some other properties contained in each Person (e.g. there is also a Country, Age,... for each Person). Maybe you can help me there too?

---

Thanks again Sergey. Solved my problem by implementing an Header class which implements the ICompareable interface.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<Header, Person>> PersonGroups

 public class Header: IComparable<Header>
 {
     public Header(string firstname, string lastname)
     {
        Firstname= firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
     }

     public string Firstname{ get; set; }
     public string Lastname{ get; set; }

     public int CompareTo(Header that)
     {
       if (this.Firstname == that.Firstname&& this.Lastname == that.Lastname)
          return 0;
       else
           return -1;
     }
  }
```

My query now looks like this:

```
PersonGroups= persons.OrderByDescending(p => p.Timestamp)
                .GroupConsecutive(p => new Header(p.Firstname, p.Lastname));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to order results by timestamp first. And only then group this ordered sequence by consecutive people:

```
var query = 
  people.OrderByDescending(p => p.Timestamp.TimeOfDay)
        .GroupConsecutive(p => String.Format("{0} {1}", p.Firstname, p.Lastname))
        .Select(g => new {
             Header = g.Key,
             Content = String.Join("\n", g.Select(p => p.Timestamp.TimeOfDay))
        });
```

You will need [GroupConsecutive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484271/470005) implementation, which creates groups of consecutive items based on same value of provided selector (full name in your case).

For your sample input result is:

```
[
  {
    "Header": "Markus Fert",
    "Content": "11:23:00"
  },
  {
    "Header": "John Deer",
    "Content": "11:12:00\n06:34:00"
  },
  {
    "Header": "Tom Kin",
    "Content": "04:22:00\n03:49:00"
  },
  {
    "Header": "John Deer",
    "Content": "03:12:00"
  },
  {
    "Header": "Tom Kin",
    "Content": "01:12:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow that is absolutely great! Thanks Sergey, works like a charm, I got my required groups now. 
I got one more problem - edited my question about that. Maybe you can help me there too? But thank you so much anyway!

Comment: @sust86 if you want `IGrouping<Header,Person>` instead of `IGrouping<string, Person>` then just make your Header class implement IComparable - it is required by default comparer to compare grouping keys

Comment: Nevermind, corrected a mistake in my IComparable of PersonGroups. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the built-in link operator `Aggregate`.

First I need to order the list by descending timestamp and then I created a name formatter function.

```
var op = people
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Timestamp)
    .ToArray();

Func<Person, string> toName = p =>
    String.Format("{0} {1}", p.Firstname, p.Lastname);
```

Now I can build the query:

```
var query =
    op
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(new []
        {
            new
            {
                Name = toName(op.First()),
                Timestamps = new List<string>()
                {
                    op.First().Timestamp.ToShortTimeString(),
                },
            },
        }.ToList(), (a, p) =>
        {
            var name = toName(p);
            if (name == a.Last().Name)
            {
                a.Last().Timestamps.Add(p.Timestamp.ToShortTimeString());
            }
            else
            {
                a.Add(new
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Timestamps = new List<string>()
                    {
                        p.Timestamp.ToShortTimeString(),
                    },
                });
            }
            return a;
        });
```

I got this result:

[image: result]